# EntityFramework Code First manually set relation to two columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let say we have a binary tree with node structure like this:

```
public class Node
{
   public int NodeId { get; set; }
   public virtual Node ParentNode {get; set; }
   public virtual Node LeftChildNode {get; set; }
   public virtual Node RightChildNode {get; set; }
}
```

When using Code First, the Node table in database appears with columns:

ParentNode_NodeId,

LeftChildNode_NodeId,

RightChildNode_NodeId

Is it possible to manually set the relation that table will be without ParentNode_NodeId column and when asking in code for ParentNode (let say someNode.ParentNode) would be interpreted as

```
Select * from Node Where LeftChildNode_NodeId = someNode.NodeId or RightChildNode_NodeId = someNode.NodeId;
```

?

I need it because I have an error in situation when under the Node that is saved in database i try to add more than one Node under each other. For example:

```
Node parentNode = dbContext.Node.Find(1);
parentNode.LeftChildNode = new Node();
parentNode.LeftChildNode.LeftChildNode = new Node();

dbContext.SaveChanges(); <---- here is problem because parentNode.LeftChildNode has no id
```

Is it possible to make that type of action without making incomprehensible code ?

Comment: what is the error, the text of the exception ?

Comment: make sure ALL and parentnode and leftnodes are set before saving. ef must be able to fill in blanks(Ids).  Your code snippet suggests left childnode.leftchildnode doesst have parent node nav property set.

Comment: I added code parentNode.LeftChildNode.ParentNode = parentNode and the same for RightNode, but still I get an error: "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. 
Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. 
See the InnerException for details."

Comment: And in InnerException: "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."

Comment: Have you tried `[Column("Whateveryoulike")]` Data Annotation above the properties? More on that:[EF Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx)